# cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'ConsoleApp3.Program.Status'

Tags: c#

I'm practising doing code, I'm a beginner, and for some reason it's not working.

I've searched for some solutions, but I have found nothing in this matter.

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum Status { single, taken };

        public class Person
        {
            public string name;
            public int age;

            public string status;

             public Person(string _name, int _age, Status _status)
            {
                _name = name;
                _age = age;
                _status = status;

            }
            public void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name );
                Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age );
                Console.WriteLine("Status: " + status);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Person Jackk = new Person("Jack", 20, Status.single);
            Jackk.Print();


            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it would write all the information about the person, but it outputs the stuff in the Print void, but it doesn't use any of the variables, it will just print for example- Age : 0, even though it's set to 20.

I've got some messages about this. It says about the _age, _name, etc. that the value assigned to them is never used. But why?

Sorry if it's obvious, I'm still a beginner.

(the error says: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'ConsoleApp3.Program.Status'), but if I removed the status thing completely, it would still not assign the variables to the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because assigment operator takes value from variable on left of = and assigns it to the variable at the right of =

Change constructor to:

```
public Person(string _name, int _age, Status _status)
        {
            name = _name;
            age = _age;
            status = _status;

        }
```

You pass Status enum that is why your field should be as well of type Status

Change status field to:

```
public Status status;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Issue 1:

In parameterized constructor of `Person` class you are assigning class variables  to the parameters which you are passing to the constructor.

You need to do it in opposite way,

```
 Person Jackk = new Person("Jack", 20, Status.single);
```

Values which you are passing while creating instance get stored in variables defined as a parameters in constructor that are `(string _name, int _age, Status _status)`

You need to change code in constructor like

```
public Person(string _name, int _age, Status _status)
   { 
      this.name = _name; //name = "Jack";
      this.age = _age  // age =  20;
      this.status = _status //status =  Status.single;
   }
```

> Issue 2:

To print string value of enum you need convert enum value to string using `.ToString()` function

```
 public void Print()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name );
         Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age );
         Console.WriteLine("Status: " + status.ToString());
                                            //^^^^^^^^^^^ this was missing
    }
```

> Issue 3:

You need to define `status` variable of type `Status` inside `Person` class,

```
public Status status;
```

or if you want `status` with string data type then you need to use `ToString()` while assigning value to that variable

```
this.status = _status.ToString(); //status = "single";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor has the assignments mirrored. You are assigning the input to the constructor to what is the default values of your instance variables, swap `age = _age` etc and you should be fine.